# Determining the right order of time-domain low pass filter for desired cutoff frequency

Tags: convolution, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, demodulation, time-domain

I've been stuck on a problem regarding complex demodulation of a signal for a while and wondered if anyone could help.

Suppose I have a signal $X(t)$ such that

\begin{align}
    X(t) &= A(t)\cos(\omega t + P(t)) + \xi(t)  \\
    &= \frac{1}{2}A(t)[\exp(i(\omega t + P(t)) + \exp(-i(\omega t + P(t))] + \xi(t)
\end{align}

where the signal amplitude, $A(t)$, and phase, $P(t)$, are assumed to vary slowly relative to the frequency $\omega$ but be time-dependent.
The signal is demodulated via multiplication by $\exp(i\omega t)$
\begin{align}
    Y(t) &= X(t)\exp(i\omega t) \\
    &= \frac{1}{2}A(t)\exp(iP(t)) + \frac{1}{2}A(t)\exp(-i(2\omega t + P(t))) + \xi(t)\exp(-i\omega t)
\end{align}

We apply a low-pass filter to the demodulated signal to remove frequencies at or above $\omega$, thus removing the second and third term in the previous equation
\begin{equation}
\hat{Y}(t) = \frac{1}{2}\hat{A}(t)\exp(i\hat{P}(t))
\end{equation}
where $(\hat{\cdot})$ denotes a smoothed variable. We can finally extract the amplitude and phase with
\begin{equation}
    \hat{A}(t) = 2|\hat{Y}(t)|,\quad \exp(i\hat{P}(t)) = \frac{2\hat{Y}(t)}{\hat{A}(t)}
\end{equation}

For complex demodulation low-pass filtering can be achieved by convolving the signal with a window of length $N$. I wanted to test the quality of several window functions against a dummy signal, but to no avail. The main thing I needed to figure out is how to relate the filter order to the cutoff frequency in the low pass filter.

In my research I'm dealing with hour long signals and focusing on frequencies in the range 1-10mHz ($10^{-3}Hz$), so I make the dummy signal from the following:

```
def test_data(periods, noise=0, npts=1000, dt=1.0/24, phase = 0, amp=1):
    t = np.arange(npts, dtype=float) * dt
    
    x = noise * np.random.randn(npts)

    for p in periods:
        x += (np.cos(2 * np.pi * t / p + phase) * np.hanning(len(t)))
    
    return t, x
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(3600)*1000
freqs = freqs[(freqs>=1) & (freqs<=10)]/1000
t, x = test_data([1/f for f in [freqs[8],ulf[freqs]]], noise=0, 
                     npts=3600,
                     dt=1)
```

Which yields the following
[image]

I believe that a good filter and/or filter order should be able to extract the correct amplitude information at the 2 frequencies that make up the signal, without much leakage into other frequencies. Since the cutoff frequency is at -3dB of the filter frequency response, I thought that seeking the order corresponding this attenuation would be the correct way forward:

```
from numpy.fft import fft, fftshift
res=[]
ff=[]

m = ['blackman','hanning','hamming','bartlett','kaiser','boxcar']
for method in m:
    rr=[]
    for nf in np.arange(51,3600,2):
        if method=='blackman':
            win = np.blackman(nf)
        elif method=='hanning':
            win = np.hanning(nf)
        elif method=='hamming':
            win = np.hamming(nf)
        elif method=='bartlett':
            win = np.bartlett(nf)
        elif method=='kaiser':
            win = np.kaiser(nf,3)
        elif method=='boxcar':
            win = boxcar(nf)

        A2 = fft(win,3601) / (nf/2)
        mag = 2*np.abs(fftshift(A2))
        freq = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, len(A2))
        with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
            response = 20 * np.log10(mag)
        response = np.clip(response, -100, 100)
        rr.append(response)
    res.append(rr)
```

[image]

Yet running the complex demodulation at each $f$ with the corresponding -3dB order isn't performing as I'd expected

[image]

compared to setting $N=2/f$ which yields better results:
[image]

Am I just completely missing the mark here?

Comment: Typically you would have an SNR target of your result that you need to achieve and from this along with the detailed demodulation approach that establishes "Signal" in SNR, we can easily determine the performance requirements on the filter. I also prefer using the least squares algorithm for designing the filter in most applications over windowing approaches which are sub-optimum.